# How to use CustomList data in InfoPath Expression?

Tags: infopath, custom-list

How can I read/use the CustomList data in InfoPath Expression/Rule ?

I want to take necessary action after reading the data of CustomList using Rule/Expression for my calculation.

I don't want to bind this data to dropdown list. That's I have done it.

But I want to apply rule on my textbox based on my CustomList declared in my SharePoint site.

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly. But Do you retrieve data in textbox and after that you want to apply rule?

Comment: Yes. I have 2 textboxes. I have stored start & end date in each textbox respectively. I want to find working days in the other textbox based on holiday declared in customList which is coming in these start & end date. That's why I want to apply rule for this.

Comment: I have not tried but i think it will work.. Try this....                                       http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/calculate-date-difference-infopath-rules-formulas.htm                                                                                                            http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/calculate-date-difference-infopath-browser-form-c-sharp-code.htm

Comment: I have used this. Its working fine. But now just I need to add(consider) the Holidays which are declared in my CustomList, which is fall in between the start & end date.

Comment: Then you need to compare one by one date which is fall in between start date and end date with holiday date from custom list.

Comment: That's I dont know how to do it. Thats the solution which I want.

Comment: Have you enable to do within custom code Or only rules?

Comment: Please try not to ask multiple near-identical questions, or the same thing phrased a different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary data connection to your CustomList. In Infopath Designer, on ribbon Data tab > Data Connections > Add... > etc.

Click **Insert Field or Group...** button where you have created Xpath expression, navigate and choose your Data field.