# How can I use CustomList in InfoPath Rule?

Tags: infopath, custom-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use CustomList data in InfoPath Expression?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57113/how-to-use-customlist-data-in-infopath-expression)

This is my rule.

(substring-before(., ";") - substring-before(BegDateWN, ";") + substring-before(BegDateWN, ";") mod 7 - substring-before(., ";") mod 7) * 5 / 7 + substring-before(., ";") mod 7 - substring-before(BegDateWN, ";") mod 7 - (substring-before(., ";") mod 7 = 6) - (substring-before(BegDateWN, ";") mod 7 = 0) + 1 - count(GetDOM("daysOfTheWeek")/somestuff/holydays/hday[translate(get-DOM()/my:myFields/my:BeginDate, "-", "") <= translate(@hdayn, "-", "") and translate(get-DOM()/my:myFields/my:EndDate, "-", "") >= translate(@hdayn, "-", "")])

I want to add CustomList and its field Date instead of this XML format list "daysOfTheWeek" and its node "hdayn".

How can I use "HolidayList" and its field "Date" in this rule ?